# Subclassing uitableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 3 `uitableviewcontrollers` that all implement a `Uisearchcontroller` search bar.  Is it good practice to subclass a `uitableviewcontroller` that implements a `Uisearchcontroller` and use that subclass with the search or implement a `Uisearchcontroller` on each `tableview` controller?

I want to become a better programmer and a professor once told me if I have repeated code I should take a look to see if I do something to cut out the duplicate code.  In this case I feel like a `subclasses` controller is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the basic task of `UISearchController` on each `UITableViewControllers` is same, then it would be wise to use that subclassed `UITableViewController` as it would keep yourself from repeating the same code which goes through implementing the `UISearchController` on each `UITableViewController`